# is ABLUnit.pl library installed by default on Openedge 11.5?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

we're setting up a new windows machine and `{DLC11.5}/gui/ablunit.pl` 
is not found/installed.
It is on an older installation.

Is there some special setup/install option required to create it?
Is it perhaps part of developer studio?

Answer (score 6):

google site:progress.com ablunit.pl

ABL Unit functionaltiy is only provided as part of PDSOE - see https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000054642 - this includes what you can do to get it anyway.